# When should Flask.g be used?

Tags: python, flask

I [saw](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/CHANGES) that `g` will move from the request context to the app context in Flask 0.10, which made me confused about the intended use of `g`.

My understanding (for Flask 0.9) is that:

- `g` lives in the request context, i.e., created afresh when the requests starts, and available until it ends
- `g` is intended to be used as a "request blackboard", where I can put stuff relevant for the duration of the request (i.e., set a flag at the beginning of the request and handle it at the end, possibly from a `before_request`/`after_request` pair)
- in addition to holding request-level-state, `g` can and should be used for resource management, i.e., holding database connections, etc.

Which of these sentences are no longer true in Flask 0.10? Can someone point me to a resource discussing the *reasons* for the change? What should I use as a "request blackboard" in Flask 0.10 - should I create my own app/extension specific thread-local proxy and push it to the context stack `before_request`? What's the point of resource management at the application context, if my application lives for a long while (not like a request) and thus the resources are never freed?

Comment: I agree, that is a pretty odd change. Hopefully mitsuhiko implements some kind of request context object to replace `g` in 0.10, else it sounds like a lot of code might start developing some devious bugs.

Comment: FWIW, Armin Ronacher (author of Flask) has released a sequel of "Advanced Flask Patterns" which shows some example code on how to use the new ``flask.g``. https://speakerdeck.com/mitsuhiko/advanced-flask-patterns-1

Comment: also a new request context implies a new app context, so it should just work fine in normal use

Answer (score 153, accepted):

[Advanced Flask Patterns](https://speakerdeck.com/mitsuhiko/advanced-flask-patterns-1), as [linked by Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083967/when-should-flask-g-be-used/15101229#comment21244306_15083967), explains some of the changes to `g` in 0.10:

- `g` now lives in the application context.
- [Every request pushes a new application context](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/1949c4a9abc174bf29620f6dd8ceab9ed3ace2eb/flask/ctx.py#L230), wiping the old one, so `g` can still be used to set flags per-request without change to code.
- The application context is popped *after* `teardown_request` is called. (Armin's presentation explains this is because things like creating DB connections are tasks which *setup* the environment for the request, and should not be handled inside `before_request` and `after_request`)

Comment: In the source code you linked to, when `app_ctx is None or app_ctx.app != self.app` is False, the old application context seems to be reused? This doesn't seem to be right, since the application context "will not be shared between requests"...

Comment: Are you referring to the [pushing of `app.app_context()`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/ctx.py#L317)? If so, it should be noted [`app_context()`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L2080-L2093) instantiates a new application context every call — it never reuses a context.

Comment: Yes that's true, but when `app_ctx is not None and app_ctx.app == self.app`, the `app_ctx = self.app.app_context()` line is _not_ executed; only `self._implicit_app_ctx_stack.append(None)` is executed in this case.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread! In a production setting, there is only one request served per thread (or greenlet). Only one `RequestContext` is pushed, so only one `AppContext` is pushed. But if [debug mode is on and a request fails, Flask saves the context](https://git.io/v7WAt), so [it can be used with the debugger](https://git.io/v7WAI). `None` is appended to the `_app_ctx_stack`, so when the request is being torn down, it knows not to pop the `AppContext` just yet. The same thing occurs with the test client, which retains the context, so it can be inspected.

Comment: So the scope of g is per request (thread) and it will not retain the value in subsequent request.

Answer (score 136):

As an addendum to the information in this thread: I've been a bit confused by the behavior of `flask.g` too, but some quick testing has helped me to clarify it. Here's what I tried out:

```
from flask import Flask, g
app = Flask(__name__)

with app.app_context():
    print('in app context, before first request context')
    print('setting g.foo to abc')
    g.foo = 'abc'
    print('g.foo should be abc, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))

    with app.test_request_context():
        print('in first request context')
        print('g.foo should be abc, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))
        print('setting g.foo to xyz')
        g.foo = 'xyz'
        print('g.foo should be xyz, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))

    print('in app context, after first request context')
    print('g.foo should be abc, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))

    with app.test_request_context():
        print('in second request context')
        print('g.foo should be abc, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))
        print('setting g.foo to pqr')
        g.foo = 'pqr'
        print('g.foo should be pqr, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))

    print('in app context, after second request context')
    print('g.foo should be abc, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))
```

And here's the output that it gives:

```
in app context, before first request context
setting g.foo to abc
g.foo should be abc, is: abc  

in first request context
g.foo should be abc, is: abc
setting g.foo to xyz
g.foo should be xyz, is: xyz  

in app context, after first request context
g.foo should be abc, is: xyz  

in second request context
g.foo should be abc, is: xyz
setting g.foo to pqr
g.foo should be pqr, is: pqr  

in app context, after second request context
g.foo should be abc, is: pqr
```

As theY4Kman said above, "Every request pushes a new application context". And [as the Flask docs say](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/), the application context "will not be shared between requests". Now, what hasn't been explicitly stated (although I guess it's implied from these statements), and what my testing clearly shows, is that you should **never** explicitly create multiple request contexts nested inside one application context, because `flask.g` (and co) doesn't have any magic whereby it functions in the two different "levels" of context, with different states existing independently at the application and request levels.

The reality is that "application context" is potentially quite a misleading name, because `app.app_context()` **is** a [per-request context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#lifetime-of-the-context), exactly the same as the ["request context"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/#lifetime-of-the-context). Think of it as a "request context lite", only required in the case where you need some of the variables that normally require a request context, but you don't need access to any request object (e.g. when running batch DB operations in a shell script). If you try and extend the application context to encompass more than one request context, you're asking for trouble. So, rather than my test above, you should instead write code like this with Flask's contexts:

```
from flask import Flask, g
app = Flask(__name__)

with app.app_context():
    print('in app context, before first request context')
    print('setting g.foo to abc')
    g.foo = 'abc'
    print('g.foo should be abc, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))

with app.test_request_context():
    print('in first request context')
    print('g.foo should be None, is: {0}'.format(g.get('foo')))
    print('setting g.foo to xyz')
    g.foo = 'xyz'
    print('g.foo should be xyz, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))

with app.test_request_context():
    print('in second request context')
    print('g.foo should be None, is: {0}'.format(g.get('foo')))
    print('setting g.foo to pqr')
    g.foo = 'pqr'
    print('g.foo should be pqr, is: {0}'.format(g.foo))
```

Which will give the expected results:

```
in app context, before first request context
setting g.foo to abc
g.foo should be abc, is: abc  

in first request context
g.foo should be None, is: None
setting g.foo to xyz
g.foo should be xyz, is: xyz  

in second request context
g.foo should be None, is: None
setting g.foo to pqr
g.foo should be pqr, is: pqr
```

Comment: Upvoted because of the last paragraph, flask's contexts are quite confusing to be understood at first. From the name, you get the feeling that request context is per request and that the app context exists even after a request or is not affected by it's lifetime.

Comment: It may be helpful to think of `app_context` as "WSGI app context", as WSGI apps are callables invoked to handle each request. So the `app_context` doesn't persist the entire lifetime of the Flask app, but rather the lifetime of the WSGI app.