# Access object across views in Flask without instantiating for every request

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make a call to an outside API that authenticates the user to some domain and returns an object `B`. This `B` object should be accessible across multiple view functions, but I don't want to instantiate it every request in `before_request` or store the auth information in the session or database because it is sensitive.

Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083967/when-should-flask-g-be-used) I thought I might be able to use the `g` object, but I get `AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'B'` when I try to access the object in another function.

The only thing that has worked so far is initializing `B` as a global variable, but that doesn't seem like good practice or secure.

How can I create and store this object so that it is accessible across multiple view functions?

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if g.user is not None and g.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        pw = form.password.data
        g.B = Bindings(domain='somewebsite.com', user=email, auth=pw)

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)

@app.route('/devices')
def devices():
    devices = g.B.get_all_devices()
    return render_template('home/devices.html', devices=devices)
```