# what does this line do flask.g.auth.logged_in?

Tags: python, flask

I was going through this piece of code:-

```
def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
    """ Decorated function, actually does the work. """
    if not flask.g.auth.logged_in:
        flask.flash('Login required', 'errors')
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for(
            'login_fedora', next=flask.request.url))

    return function(*args, **kwargs)
```

but i am not getting what this line `if not flask.g.auth.logged_in:` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flask.g --> g lives in application context.
Check [Flask-Usage of G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083967/when-should-flask-g-be-used)
The line on which you are having doubts on is basically checking whether user is already logged-in (authenticated) or not. If not, it re-directs to login page.
Think about it like, you see a facebook picture viewable without logging in, then you clicked on 'share' but to share, one must be logged-in, this is where functions like the one you have posted comes into picture.