# What's the difference between current_app and g context variable?

Tags: python, flask

Both `current_app` and `g` are application context variables, so they are loaded and unloaded with each request, so anything data stored on them will only be available within the same request.

The only difference I can see is that `g` starts empty at the beginning of each request, while `current_app` starts with some attributes (like `config`) that are copied from the application object. But that wouldn't justify having `g` object at all, since one could just as easily store new information on `current_app`.

What's the difference that I don't see?

Answer (score 8):

I believe that you read the docs on [`g`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.g) and on [`current_app`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.current_app). So what i could understand from it:

`current_app`:

> Points to the application handling the request. This is useful for extensions that want to **support multiple applications** running side by side.

[emphasis mine]

So you are getting context of current app, while `g` stores everything, from [source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/globals.py):

> ```
> def _lookup_app_object(name):
>     top = _app_ctx_stack.top
>     if top is None:
>         raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
>     return getattr(top, name)
>
> def _find_app():
>     top = _app_ctx_stack.top
>     if top is None:
>         raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
>     return top.app
>
> current_app = LocalProxy(_find_app)
> g = LocalProxy(partial(_lookup_app_object, 'g'))
> ```

So if you're running several applications, `current_app` would reference to current one(obvious, right), and `g` to everything.

Comment: Even if I run several applications, why do i need `g`? Any data I put on it seems to survive exactly until the end of the current request (which I assume will be always handled by one application). So why not put my data onto `current_app`?

Comment: But separating contexts isn't good reason for that. You store application specific context in `current_app` and everything else in `g` that that application specific?

Comment: `current_app`: specific to current context of the application. `g` : globally for entire application.

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ In this case, could you clarify the difference between the "the current context of the applications" and the "entire application", please?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

> When the request starts, a RequestContext is created and pushed, which
>   creates and pushes an AppContext first if a context for that
>   application is not already the top context. While these contexts are
>   pushed, the current_app, g, request, and session proxies are available
>   to the original thread handling the request.

When you are on a browser and made your first request, the and application context is created and pushed out to the stack and then on the top of the stack, the request context are created and popped out.  The point is - the application context is at the bottom of the request stack data structure.

More so on g: It's a namespace object that can store data during an application context. This is a good place to store resources during a request. `g is a special object that is unique for each request. It is used to store data that might be accessed by multiple functions during the request.` The connection is stored and reused instead of creating a new connection if get_db is called a second time in the same request. 
more: [When should Flask.g be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083967/when-should-flask-g-be-used?rq=1)

Side note: Checkout the user for Context Processors (The dict returned by that, is available directly to all the templates )