# How does Flask handle request with existing application context?

Tags: python, flask

According to the [Flask 0.12 document](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#locality-of-the-context) (emphasis mine):

> The application context is created and destroyed as necessary. It
>   never moves between threads and **it will not be shared between
>   requests...**

However, the relevant part of the [source code](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.12-maintenance/flask/ctx.py#L313) seems a bit strange to me:

```
# Before we push the request context we have to ensure that there
# is an application context.
app_ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top
if app_ctx is None or app_ctx.app != self.app:
    app_ctx = self.app.app_context()
    app_ctx.push()
    self._implicit_app_ctx_stack.append(app_ctx)
else:
    self._implicit_app_ctx_stack.append(None)
```

As you can see, when `app_ctx is None or app_ctx.app != self.app` is `False`, nothing is done except `None` is appended to `self._implicit_app_ctx_stack`, so I suspect the existing application context is re-used, i.e. shared between requests.

To make things even more complicated, [this experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33382823/5399734) also shows that application context is preserved between requests (because after the first request, `g.foo` still contains `xzy`).

That said, the document is inconsistent with both the source code and an experiment. So how on earth does Flask handle a coming request, when there is an existing application context?